# Custom Notification layout in X10

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using a custom notification layout in my app. It works fine in all other devices but not in Sony Xperia series. There the notifications doesn't show up.

Example:

When using `setLatestEventInfo()` and making a standard `Notification`, it works correctly. But when I use a custom layout it doesn't work on Sony Xperia series mobiles.

Code for the notification:

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customlayout);
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "testing";
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationTest.this, 0, intent, 0);

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    Notification mNotification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    mNotification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    mNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, tickerText);                
    mNotification.contentView = contentView;

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
```

This code above works perfectly on other devices, but Xperia series have problems

Any ideas?

EDIT: Standard custom layout from Android developer's guide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          />
<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#000"
          />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post `res/layout/customlayout.xml`? Maybe there's something in there that will give us a clue.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sure. Like you see it's the standard one like in Android developer website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this sounds like an Xperia bug. My guess is that Sony made some mods that assume a certain structure for the notification drawer content and it's failing. There might be LogCat messages to that effect.

If you have access to the device for testing, one thing you could try is to copy `status_bar_latest_event_content.xml` from the proper platform in your SDK into your project, and try using it. That is the standard `Notification` layout for the `RemoteViews`, if you don't override it.

If it succeeds, then my theory above is probably correct, and you can incrementally adjust that layout until it stops working, in which case you know what Sony's dependency is and can try to figure out how to work around it.

If you try the layout and it fails with the same symptoms, then Sony perhaps broke the whole notion of custom notification layouts. In that case, short of using `Build` to identify failing devices and working around them, you may need to stick to standard layouts.

Comment: This must be a bug, it works with other phones. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Julian Assange: The error indicates that something is trying to call `setImageResource()` on a `RelativeLayout`. I'm not even sure where the `RelativeLayout` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to be fixed on the latest versions to come of the firmware for Sony Ericsson Xperia devices. However, to ensure that we are looking at the same thing, it would be of great help if you could provide us with the LogCat verbose logs, please.